# How can I fix the issue I have with installation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

So I've been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 amd64 for a day and I keep having the same problem.

First off, here's some info on my system:

```
CPU: Intel 15-4690k
GPU: Nvidia geforce GTX 970 acx 2.0
Mobo: Gigabyte GA-Z97MX-GAMING 5
RAM: Gskill Ares (4x4gb)
```

I'm trying to install on a new SP600 SSD 128gb from ADATA from an iso burned on a  kingston 8gb data traveler usb 3.0 (I know usb 3.0 caused problems with iso images of windows 7, could there be a similar thing with ubuntu?)

So, every time I boot from the usb, I get to a boot screen (in picture) 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/zI1EUSt.jpg]
(the option highlighted in white is "try without installing")
When I try to select an option, the screen goes grey and it gives me an error code "Failed to create 0X80000080,-22"

Can anyone help me fix this?